# how can i split a string before the second occurance of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say i have the string `NYKMIANYKCLE`, i want to split it into a list that has only `NYKMIA` and `NYKCLE`(splits right before second occurance of `'NYK'`).  Is there a way to do it in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to find all substrings starting with `NYK`, not containing another `NYK` or followed by the end-of-string character:

```
>>> s = 'NYKMIANYKCLE'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'NYK.+?(?=NYK|$)', s)
['NYKMIA', 'NYKCLE']
```

The first `?` ensures the search is non-greedy; one substring at a time, while `(?=NYK|$)` enforces an assertion that the substring is preceding the next `NYK...` substring or the end-of-string character `$`.

---

More tests:

```
>>> s = 'NYKMIANYKCLENYKjahsja'
>>> re.findall(r'NYK.+?(?=NYK|$)', s)
['NYKMIA', 'NYKCLE', 'NYKjahsja']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
string = 'NYKMIANYKCLE'
substring = 'NYK'

first_index = string.index(substring)
second_index = string.index(substring, first_index + len(substring))
print string[:second_index], string[second_index:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was about splitting, this can be done with the new [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex),
 which allows zero width characters for splitting

```
import regex
s='NYKMIANYKCLE'
print(regex.split('(?V1)(?=NYK)',s))
```

**output**

```
['', 'NYKMIA', 'NYKCLE']
```

---

**UPDATE**

To avoid splitting at the beginning of the line

```
print(regex.split('(?V1)[^^](?=NYK)',s))
```

**output**

```
['NYKMI', 'NYKCLE']
```

**explanation**

```
(?V1)      #Forces new version 2 of split which allows zero width chars for split
[^^]       #don't take line beginning as split
(?=NYK)    #take a position as split if the position is followed by NYK
```